# Question about IFrame

Tags: iframe

I had been going through Iframe related questions and got stuck with this.

> They break the one-document-per-URL
>   paradigm, which is essential for the
>   proper functioning of the web (think
>   bookmarks, deep-links, search engines,
>   ...).

Moreover, if I ask you to tell me the difference between Iframes and Frames, what is the easiest way to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Frame allows you to display multiple documents on page.

They all have distinct URLs which are hidden from you. So, you cannot bookmark them separately.

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is a frame in an otherwise normal document.

Normal frames are placed in a document which consists entirely of frames (plus, hopefully, some fallback content from user agents that don't support them).